# Distance between number and unit changes in tables for siunitx in LaTeX

Tags: pdftex, siunitx

When using `siunitx` to put number with units aligned with the decimal point (, in this case) in a table I see a strange behavior that the distance between the number and the unit is not existent for small numbers but somehow keeps increasing dependent on the number of digits...

```
\documentclass[DIN, a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage[detect-all,locale=DE]{siunitx}

\newcommand{\cbm}{\unit{\cubic\metre}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{S}
    \toprule
    \textbf{Count} \\ \toprule
    1,2 \cbm       \\ \midrule
    1,23 \cbm      \\ \midrule
    1,234 \cbm     \\ \midrule
    25,1 \cbm      \\ \midrule
    256,1 \cbm     \\ \midrule
    2567,1 \cbm    \\ \midrule
    2567,123 \cbm  \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

How can I prevent that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to work when using the column option: `[table-format=5.7,table-align-text-post = false]` and then adding a fixed space to the unit definition:`\newcommand{\cbm}{\,\unit{\cubic\metre}}`.

Full code:

```
\documentclass[DIN, a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage[detect-all,locale=DE]{siunitx}

\newcommand{\cbm}{\,\unit{\cubic\metre}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{S[table-format=5.7,table-align-text-post = false]}
    \toprule
    \textbf{Count} \\ \toprule
    1,2 \cbm       \\ \midrule
    1,23 \cbm      \\ \midrule
    1,234 \cbm     \\ \midrule
    25,1 \cbm      \\ \midrule
    256,1 \cbm     \\ \midrule
    2567,1 \cbm    \\ \midrule
    2567,123 \cbm  \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```